# java Timer TimerTask multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

I'm using Timer and TimerTask to long poll for new messages for a chat application.
I would like to examine two "slightly" different possibilities:

**1 :** Timer declared as local variable

```
public List<MessageBean> getLastMessages(...) {
    [...]
    Timer timer = new Timer(true); //**Timer declared as local variable**
    while (someCondiction) {
        MessagesTimerTask returnMessagesTask = new MessagesTimerTask([...]);
        timer.schedule(returnMessagesTask, 6000);
        synchronized (listMessageBean) {
            listMessageBean.wait();
            //notify is called in the MessagesTimerTask which extends TimerTask
        }
    }
}
```

***Problem:** Every time i call the method, i can see that a new thread is created, [Timer-1], [Timer-2], etc.. And in Eclipse Debug window they all seem to be running even after the **getLastMessages(..)** finishes running and returns a value to the client.
This may cause a huge problem if the timers are actually using threads, and after few transactions the server will eventually consume all the machine resources.

**2 :** Timer declared as local field

```
private final Timer timer = new Timer(true); //**Timer declared as local field**

public List<MessageBean> getLastMessages(...) {
    [...]
    while (someCondiction) {
        MessagesTimerTask returnMessagesTask = new MessagesTimerTask([...]);
        timer.schedule(returnMessagesTask, 6000);
        synchronized (listMessageBean) {
            listMessageBean.wait();
            //notify is called in the MessagesTimerTask which extends TimerTask
        }
    }
}
```

***Problem:** every time i call the method, the same thread is used [Thread-1], but i'm not sure if i make two consecutive calls, the latter will cancel/override the former (the class is @Autowired by spring) ?

Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Comment: Choice 2) will be very much effective as per performance point of view.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani ok but if i call the service twice, the object timer will be the same object in both calls.. won't the second call reschedule another task thus cancelling the previous one ?

Comment: and somebody just went and downvoted all of my questions in the same minute ... !!

Comment: @jidma: It seems someone serially downvoted you. You can report this on meta.stackoverflow if you wish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Timer.java.html) of the `schedule` method:

```
190       public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay) {
191           if (delay < 0)
192               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative delay.");
193           sched(task, System.currentTimeMillis()+delay, 0);
194       }
```

and the `sched` method:

```
386       private void sched(TimerTask task, long time, long period) {
387           if (time < 0)
388               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal execution time.");
389   
390           // Constrain value of period sufficiently to prevent numeric
391           // overflow while still being effectively infinitely large.
392           if (Math.abs(period) > (Long.MAX_VALUE >> 1))
393               period >>= 1;
394   
395           synchronized(queue) {
396               if (!thread.newTasksMayBeScheduled)
397                   throw new IllegalStateException("Timer already cancelled.");
398   
399               synchronized(task.lock) {
400                   if (task.state != TimerTask.VIRGIN)
401                       throw new IllegalStateException(
402                           "Task already scheduled or cancelled");
403                   task.nextExecutionTime = time;
404                   task.period = period;
405                   task.state = TimerTask.SCHEDULED;
406               }
407   
408               queue.add(task);
409               if (queue.getMin() == task)
410                   queue.notify();
411           }
412       }
```

From here you can clearly see that a queue is being used to store tasks internally, meaning that later tasks will not overwrite the earlier ones. If you also check the `mainLoop` method in the file, you can see that it takes tasks from the queue one-by-one ordered by their schedule time and executes them.

So it should not be a problem to schedule multiple tasks on the same `Timer` object.

As a side-note, consider replacing `Timer` with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` available since Java 1.5.

Comment: thx for the side-note, replacing timer with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor solved also some other thread related problems